# Is there a way to disable the "enter a password to unlock the disk" prompt for a disk?

Tags: macos, mount

I installed macOS on a partition in an external drive which is encrypted with FireVault. I don't want to mount it when I plug it in, but I get the "enter a password to unlock the disk" prompt whenever I plug the drive in (which is fairly often) and I need to escape out of it every time. Is there a way to stop showing this prompt, while not having to mount it? You can prevent it from coming up with the "[remember password in keychain]" option but that would mount it every time.

Comment: The technical thing you are looking for is preventing automount of a specific partition or container. I’m not sure if macOS still uses autoFS but that’s where you’d have to start looking

Comment: Perhaps this: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-disable-automount-on-a-specific-external-USB-disk-in-Mac-OS-X

Answer (score -1):

I found this, which is basically the same as the quora.com method (link above):

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/11/24/prevent-partitions-from-mounting-mac/

However, for me, although it DOES prevent the volume from being mounted on startup, so far it DOES NOT prevent the popup "enter a password to unlock the disk".

Comment: This doesn't work for me with encrypted APFS partitions under Catalina (10.15), even if you specify the partition type as apfs in /etc/fstab. My suspicion is that this solution only works if you store the secondary Filevault passwords in Keychain, but that defeats the purpose of separating partitions.